# Is there a simple way to define/solve for a null cone for a general spacetime geometry?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I'm wondering if there's any simple way to define and solve for a null cone for a general spacetime geometry in $n+1$ dimensions, given its vertex $p^\mu$. I can't seem to find a simple way to do it that doesn't involve solving for null geodesics. It seems like it's something that should be in a lot of GR textbooks, but I can't seem to find a simple alternative (perhaps I'm not looking hard enough, but that's why I'm asking).

So far, the best I can do is to define it as the $n$-surface formed by the family of null geodesics $y_{\bf\Omega}^\mu$ passing through some spacetime point $p^\mu$, where $\bf\Omega$ is a combination of $n-1$ angles that distinguishes the curves (at $p^\mu$, it's the collection of angles specifying the direction of the null curve).

The problem is, I'm interested in doing a foliation of spacetime using future or past null cones with respect to some timelike curve $\gamma$, and would like to define the null cones in the form of a constraint:

$C_{\gamma}(x^\mu)=\tau$

Where $\tau$ is the proper time along the timelike curve $\gamma$. This constraint satisfies:

$U(C_{\gamma})=0$

Where $U$ is the vector field defined using the tangent vectors to $y_{\bf\Omega}^\mu$ (this can be defined for all spacetime, if you take the union of all the null cones along $\gamma$). In any case, I still have to solve for the null geodesics, given what I have so far.

I'm not a fan of solving for all the null geodesics at every point along the curve, so I'm looking for a simpler way to do it.

I have the feeling that there should be a simpler way of defining and solving for null cones--it seems like they've been extensively studied in GR. Is there any way to do this without resorting to solving for the null geodesics? In particular, has anyone written down a general constraint form for the null cone?

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer the *source* of your question:

> I'm interested in doing a foliation of spacetime using future or past null cones with respect to some timelike curve $\gamma$, and would like to define the null cones in the form of a constraint ...

**That** is a priori impossible. In an arbitrary space-time geometry, there can be [focal and conjugate points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_points). Unless you are willing to assume from the start some bounds on the null injectivity radius (to be infinite), you can not in general foliate an entire space-time with null cones (mostly because the cones will likely cease to be cones after some affine parameter).

---

With that said, if you are defining null hypersurfaces, you *can* solve instead for the eikonal equation. That is, let $u$ be a parameter describing your null cones (in the sense that $u:M\to \mathbb{R}$ is a real valued function on your manifold, and that its level sets are "null cones"). Then a necessary equation satisfied by the function $u$ is

$$ g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu u\partial_\nu u = 0 $$

the difficulty of this approach is to "match" the tip of the cone to be precisely along the curve $\gamma$, but regularity issues like this has to manifest itself somewhere or another.

Comment: As an example to the first point: consider yourself in Schwarzschild, and your time-like curve $\gamma$ sits exactly on the photon sphere. Then for each point $p$ on the photon sphere, there are infinitely many times $\tau_1, \tau_2, \ldots$ such that $p$ is "on the light cone" of $\gamma(\tau_i)$.

Comment: Good point. I was mostly thinking about it quasi-locally, and didn't consider the global implications of what I wanted to do.